# Check value of starting characters of an input Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text field that can accept input of any kind. Based on the input, I need to make some fields hidden and others unhidden. However I want to put another condition within the first condition to check for the first 3 characters of the input value

Here is my code for the first condition:

```
$("#accountcodes").live("focusout",function(){
    var code = $(this).val();
    if(code>30000){ 
    alert("T1 to T4 codes needed");
    $(this).parents("tr").find('#T1').removeAttr('hidden','hidden');
    $(this).parents("tr").find('#T2').removeAttr('hidden','hidden');
    $(this).parents("tr").find('#T3').removeAttr('hidden','hidden');
    $(this).parents("tr").find('#T4').removeAttr('hidden','hidden');    

    }

    })
```

I want to put another condition within the if statement(if within an if) to check if the first 3 characters start with 310 or 311 then do something else e.g if a user inputs 31102, then another field is unhidden e.t.c I am not sure how to do that in Jquery. should I use regex? do I take the value of input and cut out the first three characters and check it?
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you just want to know about `substr()`? `code.substr(0,3)` would get you the first three characters.

Alternatively, you may want to use a regex to find 310 and 311 more easily, in which case you want `code.match(/^31[01]/)` instead.

Comment: For being the first one to answer. I award your answer as the correct one. Didn't know about substring and the rest.

Answer (score 2):

```
var code = $(this).val();
var firstThreeChars = code.substr(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems your values will always be numeric. You don't need much jquery to achieve this.

```
$("#accountcodes").live("focusout",function(){
    var code = $(this).val();
    if(code > 30000){
        //Note: For any non-numeric value, this condition will always be false

        alert("T1 to T4 codes needed");
        var p = $(this).parents("tr");
        p.find('#T1, #T2, #T3, #T4').removeAttr('hidden');

        if ((code - 31000) > 102){ // Your other condition check can look like this
            // unhide other fields
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this will help. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question have your answer you can do it many ways

1. Sub-string the value and check the value.
   2.go for contains key word of jquery [ api.jquery.com/contains-selector/][1]